# Memorylessness of residence times for a Markov process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I'm stuck on the trivial problem of showing memorylessness of holding (residence) times for a continuous time homogeneous Markov chain on finite state space.

I have a homogeneous Markov process $x(t), x(0)=x_0$ on finite state space defined in the usual way. I use a sequence of times $\{t_n, t_0 = 0\}$ and states $\{x_n\}$ to construct the chain, so that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}\left[ x(t_{n+1})=x_{n+1}\big\vert x(t_n)=x_n,\dots,x(0)=x_0 \right] &= \mathbb{P}\left[x_{n+1},t_{n+1}\big\vert x_n,t_n,\dots,x_0\right] \\&=\mathbb{P}\left[ x(t_{n+1})=x_{n+1} \big\vert x(t_n)=x_n\right]\\&=\mathbb{P}\left[x_{n+1},t_{n+1}\big\vert x_n,t_n\right],
\end{aligned}
$$
with the Markov property satisfied. I can further write:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[x_{n+1},t_{n+1}\big\vert x_n,t_n,\dots,x_0\right] = \mathbb{P}\left[x_{n+1} \big\vert x_n,t_n,\dots,x_0\right]\mathbb{P}\left[t_{n+1}\big\vert x_n,t_n,\dots,x_0\right],
$$
to obtain the Markov property for $\{t_n\}$:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[t_{n+1}\big\vert x_n,t_n,\dots,x_0\right] = \mathbb{P}\left[t_{n+1}\big\vert x_n,t_n\right].
$$
I now consider a sequence of holding times $\{h_k:t_n=\sum_{i=1}^nh_i\}$ and look at the cumulative distribution of $h_{n+1}$:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[x(t_n + \Delta t_1 + \Delta t_2)=x_n\big\vert x(t_n+\Delta t_1)=x_n\right] = \mathbb{P}\left[h_{n+1}>\Delta t_1 + \Delta t_2\big\vert h_{n+1}>\Delta t_1, x_n\right].
$$
The objective is to show that: 
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[h_{n+1}>\Delta t_1 + \Delta t_2\big\vert h_{n+1}>\Delta t_1, x_n\right] = \mathbb{P}\left[h_{n+1}>\Delta t_2\big\vert x_n\right],
$$
which I can't see how to do using the Markov properties as written above.